# Proving $|z-1|\leq ||z|-1|+|z||argz|$ where $z$ is a complex number..

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The following substitution is written: $$z=|z|e^{i \varphi}$$... and the assignment goes on to do some transformations, operations that are trivial with this and then comes to the conclusion, which is unclear to me that:

$$|\sin \frac{\varphi}{2}|<\frac{|\varphi|}{2}$$. I don't see how this is, do I need to give more context here, the lines in between..?

Comment: Can you see this geometrically? The right picture makes this inequality crystal clear.

Comment: Is this essentially that the hypothesis of a right triangle is always larger than the sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $|z-1| \le |z-|z|| + ||z|-1|.$ Now the points $z,|z|$ lie on the circle centered at $0$ of radius $|z|.$ So the straight line distance between these points is no more than the arc length between them on this circle.

Comment: (+1) as good an explanation as there is likely to be (unless someone adds a diagram).